# C# - Need help reviewing the code

Tags: c#

Here is a method I have:

```
private void ProcessExpiryDate(out DateTime cashDate, out DateTime expiryDate, out DateTime expiryDateSecond)
{
// Lots of logic here, that's why I created this method
}
```

This private method is called several times in other public methods.
And every time a call is needed, I need to do the following codes:

```
DateTime cashDate;
DateTime expiryDate;
DateTime expiryDateSecond;
ProcessExpiryDate(out cashDate, out expiryDate, out expiryDateSecond);
existingObject.CashDate = cashDate;
existingObject.ExpiryDate = expiryDate;
existingObject.ExpiryDateSecond = expiryDateSecond;
```

Is there any better suggestion to make the lines shorter during the call ?
These 7 lines I need to write in every call looks ugly.

Comment: _Need help reviewing the code_ - but first, you need help with [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: so, what do you think can make the questions better @t3chb0t ?

Comment: There is nothing to think, just read the help page and you'll know it too ;-]

Comment: A good reference about asking a **good** question: [Simon's Guide for posting a good question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6429/29371)

Answer (score 1):

It's preferable to not allow out parameters in your code.

Methods should be immutable as far as possible and not change the state of incoming data.

I would:

1. Return an object that encapsulates `cashDate`, `expiryDate`, `expiryDateSecond` (ex: `ProcessedExpiryDate` object)
2. Use a method such as SetDates as Maxim had suggested

This will allow you to turn your method call into:
    `SetDates(existingObject, ProcessExpiryDate())`

Answer (score 1):

You're not the only one who noticed this problem. With C#7 [they give us a better way to do it](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37675.c-7-0-out-parameter.aspx), with inline out parameters:

```
ProcessExpiryDate(out DateTime cashDate, 
                  out DateTime expiryDate, 
                  out DateTime expiryDateSecond);
```

But if you're not ready to leap into version 7, you could just pass the object in and let the method set the dates. Or better yet, define an interface.

```
interface IExpirable
{
    DateTime CashDate { set; }
    DateTime ExpiryDate { set; }
    DateTime ExpiryDateSecond { set; }
}

class ExistingObject : IExpirable
{
    //Define as you did before
}

private void ApplyExpiryDate(IExpirable o)
{
    o.CashDate = moe; 
    o.ExpiryDate = larry;
    o.ExpiryDateSecond = curly;
    //No need to return the modified object, because it was passed by reference
}

void MainCodeExample(ExistingObject existingObject)
{
    ApplyExpiryDate(existingObject);
}
```

Notes:

1. In keeping with common standards I switched from camelCase to PascalCase for the property names.
2. I changed "Process" to "Apply" in the method name, which I think is more likely to be understand as a method which changes the object that is passed in.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to turn your `ProcessExpiryDate` method to this?

```
private void SetDates(SomeObject existingObject)
{
    // calculate dates

    existingObject.CashDate = cashDate;
    existingObject.ExpiryDate = expiryDate;
    existingObject.ExpiryDateSecond = expiryDateSecond;
}
```

And all your code will be turned into

```
SetDates(existingObject);
```

Comment: Hi Maxim, don't you think we need the "out" parameter in your suggestion ?

Comment: @Zan nope as long as the method parameter is an object. The only thing you should make sure is that `existingObject` is not `null`.

Comment: @Zan As said by @Heslacher the only thing you need is to check `existingObject` for null.